# Count occurrences in column based on another column (date)

Tags: python, dataframe, count, time-series, columnsorting

I am trying to count the number of "Type" occurrences by what month they are in.

Daily data is given, so to group by month I tried using `.resample()` but the problem with using is that combines all the strings together in one LONG string and then I can't count the number of occurrences using `str.count()` as it returns the wrong value (it finds too many matches because it isn't looking for the EXACT pattern).

I think it has to be done in more than one step...
I have tried SO many things... I even heard there is a pivot table?

Sample data:

| Type | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Cat | 2020-01-01 |
| Cat | 2020-01-01 |
| Bird | 2020-01-01 |
| Dog | 2020-01-01 |
| Cat | 2020-02-01 |
| Cat | 2020-03-01 |
| Bird | 2020-03-01 |
| Cat | 2020-05-02 |

... For all the months over a few years...

Converted to the following format: (titles of header can be in numeric form as well)

|  | January 2020 | February 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | 4 | 1 |
| Bird | 1 | 0 |
| Dog | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Pandas does not have a standard function or typical approach to obtain your desired result. Below I've included a code snippet that gets your desired result.

If you do not mind using extra packages, there exist some packages which you can use for quicker/easier binary encoding (e.g. `category_encoder`).

```
import pandas as pd

# your data in dictionary format
d = {
  "Type":["Cat","Cat","Bird","Dog","Cat","Cat","Bird","Cat"],
  "Date":["2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-02-01","2020-03-01","2020-03-01","2020-05-02"]
}

# creata dataframe with the dates as index
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d['Type'], index=pd.to_datetime(d['Date'])) 


animals = list(df[0].unique()) # a list contaning all unique animals
ndf = pd.DataFrame(index=animals) # empty new dataframe with all animals as index

for animal in animals:
    ndf.loc[animal, df.index.month.unique()] = (  # at row = animal, insert all unique months
        (df == animal).groupby(df.index.month)    # groupby months, using .month (returns 1 for Jan)
                      .sum()                      # sum since we use bool comparison
                      .transpose()                # tranpose due to desired output format
                      .values                     # array of values to insert
    )

# convert column names back to date time and save as string in desired format
ndf.columns = pd.to_datetime(ndf.columns, format='%m').strftime('%B 2020')
```

**Result**

|  | January 2020 | February 2020 | March 2020 | May 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Bird | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Dog | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |